# Sign changing elliptic problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

Take $B_1$ the unit ball in Euclidean $N$ dimensional space and suppose $3 \le N \le 10$ and take $ 1<p< \frac{N+2}{N-2}$.   By some abstract theory there is a infinite sequence of smooth radial sign changing solutions, say $u_m$, of
$$ -\Delta u = |u|^{p-1} u $$ in $B_1$ with $ u=0$ on $ \partial B_1$.  Moreover one has $ \int_{B_1} | \nabla u_m|^2 dx \rightarrow \infty$.        For simplicity assume $p=3$ and $N=3$.   Consider the linearized operator $$L_m(\phi)= -\Delta \phi(x) - 3 (u_m(r))^2 \phi(x)$$ and consider the eigenvalues $ \{ \mu_{k,m} \}_{k \ge 1}$ of this linear operator.   I know the number of negative eigenvalues goes to infinity as $ m \rightarrow \infty$.

Question.  Is there a standard approach to get an estimate on $$ \inf \{| \mu_{k,m}|: k \ge 1 \}$$?   Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about Weyl's Law? Since $\mu_{,k,m}\to+\infty$ with $k$, you are asking, for large $m$, about the asymptotic distribution of the eigenvalues, since the minimum for a fixed, large, $m$ will be attained for some large $k$. If you are asking for an inf on $k$ and $m$, it looks like it should be zero, for that reason, since eigenvalues become close together ($N=3$, so $2/N<1$).

Comment: Thanks for the comment.    Ya I don't know anything about Weyl's Law.   It sounds like you are saying that $T_m:= \inf \{ | \mu_{k,m}|: k \ge 1 \} \rightarrow 0$ as $ m \rightarrow 0$;  which is what I was mainly interested in.  Any hope of trying to find a bound on how quick it approaches zero?

Comment: [Weyl Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl_law) is proved by comparison estimation see [these notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~stevmatt/weyl_law.pdf) or others, it's the first link in google. If you have an estimate on $u_m$ you can follow the same steps and derive the corresponding estimate for your problem?